# How do I make 2 players from one Class?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am teaching myself XNA and only started a few days ago. I am making a clone of Pong and have made a class for the Paddle:[image: PaddleClass1]

[image: PaddleClass2]

I am wondering how I can create 2 paddles one for each player from the one class.

Thanks,

TeaBelliedTitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two different instances of the class.
I suggest you **not to check for input inside your class** but **in your game loop**, so you can handle events for both instances. Pseudocode below:

```
Pong::Paddle player1(texture1, bounds1);
Pong::Paddle player2(texture2, bounds2);

while(running){
  if(keyDown == W)
    player1.setYDirection(-1);
  else if(keyDown == UP)
    player2.setDirection(-1);
  else if(keyDown == S)
    player1.setYDirection(1);
  else if(keyDown == DOWN)
    player2.setDirection(1);

  player1.update();
  player2.update();
}
```